How to get the list of all loaded assemblies ordered by dependencies
I know AppDomain.GetAssemblies can be used to get all loaded assemblies of the current app but there is no guarantee of order remarked there. I need that list but also need to make sure that dependencies are listed before their host.
For example: [B, A, A.Optional, A.Optional.Data, C] (A.Optional.Data depends on A.Optional, which in turn depends on A; A, B and C are not related so it doesn't matter what order they are in).
Is it possible?
Why I need it: I have an MyAttribute used to decorate multiple classes across multiple assemblies. At the end (final project), I need to gather them and register those classes. However the order of registering is important and A.Optional classes need classes in A registered before them to work correctly.

Just leaving a comment to update that I found out Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies so it's essentially a task of converting a tree into a sorted list (but the tree may have duplicate items and the list should not)

It is called Topological sorting. You can reuse it, for example, from this library TopoSort extension method

@SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for the keyword! Looking at it now

This wasn't asked, or may be irrelevant, or you might already realize it, but just in case: since AppDomain.GetAssemblies only lists the assemblies loaded at the time it was called, hopefully you have some other way to ensure that whatever code you are writing is called at the correct time. Specifically, at a time where you are certain all assemblies you care to include in this 'sorted dependency list' have actually been loaded.  For example, loading A.Optional (which depends on A) won't necessarily force A to load; A only gets loaded if/when the JIT actually needs it.

@SeanSkelly thank you that's a very nice and important observation. Indeed it may affects my code. I found this question to solve it.
